# how to extract a date from a string with any format?

Tags: php

for example

```
$string = "Today is March 24 2014. My Birthday is on 3/24/2014";
```

how to extract those two date with different format?

Comment: There is plenty of similar questions. To match *any* date, you need  a regex for each format you want to match (example in the dupe). Then run it through `DateTime::createFromFormat`. If this doesn't answer your question, show what you tried. Note that we cannot give you *all teh patterns*, so you have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to do this, and specify which format should be used for parsing.

If you are looking for a function that does not need a format specified, it won't work. Consider for example: `1/2/2014`. Is it Februari first, or Januari second?

So assuming your day of the month doesn't get leading zeros when under 10, it would be:

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('F j Y', 'March 24 2014');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j/Y', '3/24/2014');
```

Comment: This won't work with the OP's $string

Comment: It's still missing any clues whatsoever on how to get a date out of the entire $string in the first place. You are showing step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php
  $string = "Today is March 24 2014. My Birthday is on 3/24/2014";
  $temp=explode('.',str_replace(' My Birthday is on ','',str_replace('Today is ', '', $string)));
  echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($temp[0]));
  echo "<br/>";
  echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($temp[1]));
 ?>
```

**Output**

```
2014-03-24
2014-03-24
```

Comment: this works with the OP's example but the title says "any format"

Answer (score -2):

I know just how to extract some of the date from string,i use,this

try this then

```
preg_match('/(\d?\d [A-Za-z]+ \d\d\d\d) at (\d\d\:\d\d)/', $editdate, $matches);

print_r($matches); 
$date = $matches[1];
$time = $matches[2];
```

this will work in every case,though the code looks lil ugly,

this can work well,for the first case,you can split the string first for the second case.

Comment: did you copy that solution from somewhere else? there is no "at" in the OP's string.